# JSON marshall nullable type value in database/sql Go

Tags: sql, database, go

I am trying to figure out how one can properly marhsall nullable type (string, int, time) properly to JSON in **Go**. I know that `database/sql` provide `sql.NullTime`, `sql.NullInt`, etc but when you marshall these values, you get something like

```
{"first_name": {
  "Value": "",
  "Valid": false,
}}
```

What I really want is

```
{"first_name": null}
```

I understand that you can implement your own MarshalJSON to do this (I wrote about it here http://dennissuratna.com/marshalling-nullable-string-db-value-to-json-in-go/)

BUT I am wondering if anyone knows a better way to do this. I want to know other people know a  less tedious way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

May be late, but when searching for the same problem google report this page at a high rank, so : my solution is to define special type that surcharge NullInt64 for exemple and has and export JSON

Example for NullInt64 :

```
// NullInt64 is the same as sql.NullInt64
// But when exported to JSON it is null or the int64 val that is exported
// not a JSON containing Value and Valid properties
type NullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
}

// NullInt64 MarshalJSON interface redefinition
func (r NullInt64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if r.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(r.Int64)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
}
```

And then replace all sql.NullInt64 by NullInt64.
You can easily do the same for sql.NullString.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Create a type that embeds (e.g.) sql.NullInt and implements the json.Marshaler interface.

Comment: how is this different than what I said in the last paragraph? I do not want to implement my own MarshalJSON....

Comment: I was suggesting adding a MarshallJSON method to the individual fields (like sql.NullInt), not to the record as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to have null field, you will have to resort to a custom marshaller (or maybe, just maybe, use `*string` fields in struct and assign `nil` instead of an empty string).

However, if you look at the original goal of JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), you will notice that in JavaScript there is hardly any difference between:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"first_name": null }');
alert(obj.first_name)
```

and:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{}');
alert(obj.first_name)
```

In other words: assigning `null` to a field has the same effect as not specifying it all. And most JSON parsers work like this.

Not specifying empty fields *is* supported by the Go JSON marshaller:

```
type MyType struct {
    firstname string `json:omitempty`
}
```

In the end, it depends on what you want to do with your JSON :)

Comment: Since I am getting the value of the struct form the DB, I am using `sql.NullString` as the type, not `string`. I am not sure how `omitempty` would apply to `sql.NullString`

Comment: Ah, I see. My first advice would be not to conflate the structs you use for database access with the structs you use for JSON marshalling, but that's probably not the kind of advice you're looking for.

Comment: Well! that's an approach! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found https://github.com/volatiletech/null for nullable values in SQL and JSON.

Create a type with a nullable string like:

```
import "github.com/volatiletech/null/v9"
[...]

type Entry struct {
    Value  null.String  `json:"value"`
}
```

Set such string to null:

```
object := Entry{null.NewString("", false)}
```

After marshaling the object, it creates a JSON like

```
{
    "value": null 
}
```

Or set it to a string like:

```
object := Entry{null.NewString("Hello World", true)}
```

After marshaling the object, it creates a JSON like

```
{
    "value": "Hello World" 
}
```

Unmarshaling such JSON results in an object with a null.String in it. Due to the fact GO has no ternary operator it is a little bit "unnice" to get the value back.

```
entry := Entry{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(<the JSON>), &entry)

if entry.Value.IsValid {
    return entry.Value.String
} else {
    return ""
}
```

`Value.IsValid` will return true, if the Value in the Entry object is not null.